# jquery show / hide div on click?

Tags: jquery, class, hide, show

I'm trying to use jquery to show and hide a div onclick, and, although I'm not getting any errors, it's not showing or hiding anything either.

**EDIT - UPDATED **

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#nav-inner a").click(function() {
            var type = $(this).attr("class");
                $("div.v1 > div").not("." + type).stop().hide().end().filter("." + type).stop().show();
                return false;
    });
```

});

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($("#nav-inner")) {
                $("#nav-inner ul li a").click(function(evt) {
                        var type = $(this).attr("class");
                        var rowcount = 0;
                        $('div.v1 .vc').each(function(idx,el) {
                                if(type == 'typea') {
                                    if($(el).hasClass('typea')) {
                                                $(el).show();
                                        } else {
                                                $(el).hide();
                                        }
                                } 
                        });
                    });
    }
});
```

And here's the markup:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="nav-inner">
                <ul class="nav-inner-li">
                    <li>
                        <a class="typea" href="#"><img src="/images/typea.png"></a>
                        <a class="typea" href="#">Type A</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-content">
            <div id="content-left">
                <div class="v1">
                    <div class="vc">
                        <div class="typea">
                            <div class="title"> Title </div>
                            <div class="body"> Body </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="typeb">
                            <div class="title"> Title 2 </div>
                            <div class="body"> Body 2 </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be made much simpler.

```
$(function() {
  $("#nav-inner a").click(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("class");
    $("div.vc > div").not("." + type).stop().hide()
      .end().filter("." + type).stop().show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Your first error was `#nav-inner ul` where `#nav-inner` is actually the `ul` element. The above grabs the class from the clicked link and then selects the child of `div.v1` with that class and toggles it (shows it if hidden, hides it if not).

Comment: I always use e.preventDefault() instead of return false. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't return false only cancel current element's event? and preventDefault() stops the event chain?

Comment: Thanks...  It works, sort of... Except that I need to hide everything except the divs that have that class.  So, clicking on <a class="typea"> shows the typea divs and hides all the others...  This looks like it's doing the opposite... ?

Comment: @fredrik: `return false` is equivalent to `preventDefault()` **and** `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: I tried the revised version, and now it hides everything and doesn't show anything?  I'll put the code that I just tried in the edited version of my original post...

Comment: @phpN00b: i corrected one typo (period at the end of the line after `hide(()`) and it works perfectly now.

Comment: I saw that, and corrected it (you can see it in the edit), but it's still hiding everything?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler example ..

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#divtag').click(function(){  //use # for id and . for class
                $('#insidetag').show();     // with parameters slow,fast, or a time in milisecond
            });                             // use toggle to show and hide 
        });
    </script>

<body>
    <div id="divtag">
        <div id="insidetag">
            Click the hide and show
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your simple comment //use # for id and . for class saved me hours!! Thanks gifted!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".user-profile-info").unbind().click(function(){
    if(jQuery( ".user-profile-info" ).hasClass("collapsed")){
        jQuery('#user-profile-submenu').css('display', 'block');
        jQuery( ".user-profile-info" ).removeClass("collapsed");
    }
    else
    {       
        jQuery( ".user-profile-info" ).addClass("collapsed");
        jQuery('#user-profile-submenu').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: <div class="user-profile-info collapsed"></div>
<div id="user-profile-submenu">Content of click</div>